# Is there an Access SQL query that aggregates multiple rows into one row?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks like this:

```
A 1 
A 2 
B 1 
B 2
B 3
```

And I want to produce a result set that looks like this:

```
A 1 2 
B 1 2 3
```

First column have questions and other answers, but each answer have to be in diffrent columns. So I dont need concat like 1,2,3 in this same column.

expectation:

```
Question Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 ... 
A        1       2
B        1       2       3
```

Is there a SQL statement that will do this? I am using Access 2007.

My base query is this:

```
SELECT questions.Question, answers.Answer 
FROM ((base INNER JOIN customers ON base.Patient_ID = customers.Identyfikator) LEFT JOIN answers ON base.answer_ID = answers.ID) 
LEFT JOIN questions ON base.question_ID = questions.ID 
WHERE (((customers.Identyfikator)=[param_ID]));
```

Comment: that'd be a pivot query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `PIVOT` but the MS Access syntax is non-standard.
Try the below code:

```
TRANSFORM questions.Answer
SELECT questions.Question, answers.Answer 
FROM ((base INNER JOIN customers ON base.Patient_ID = 
customers.Identyfikator) LEFT JOIN answers ON base.answer_ID = answers.ID) 
LEFT JOIN questions ON base.question_ID = questions.ID 
WHERE (((customers.Identyfikator)=[param_ID]))
GROUP BY questions.question
PIVOT questions.Answer;
```

I have tried the query on your given sample data and I have gotten the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use `PIVOT`

Here is an exmaple:

```
SELECT Config_ID
FROM TABLE_01
GROUP BY Config_ID
PIVOT ConfigField
```

Not sure if this is exactly right as I don not have 2007 and your model to test, but try this:

```
SELECT questions.Question, answers.Answer 
FROM ((base INNER JOIN customers ON base.Patient_ID = customers.Identyfikator) LEFT JOIN answers ON base.answer_ID = answers.ID) 
LEFT JOIN questions ON base.question_ID = questions.ID 
WHERE (((customers.Identyfikator)=[param_ID]))
GROUP BY questions.question
PIVOT questions.question;
```

Comment: @caruzo: I don't see that information in your question at all. If you have details to add, edit your question and do so there where everyone can see it.

Comment: Please add that detail, hard to give you a complete answer without it. Also try building your query with the PIVOT command and then post what you have tried and the community will be willing to help.

Comment: Syntax error but I dont know where :/ It show me fragment with FROM clause, but I think it's good... damn access...